# git-core has been made obsolete by the port git

Tags: macos, git, github, repository

I want to run "repo" command on Mac (And download the code from Git repo). I was following the above **guide**:

```
http://threadeds.blogspot.com/2009/02/getting-started-with-google-android-on.html
```

When I execute the command,

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 sudo port install gmake libsdl git-core gnupg
```

**I get this error:**

I'm having the following issue while installing

```
Error: git-core has been made obsolete by the port git. Please install git instead.
Error: org.macports.configure for port git-core returned: obsolete port
Please see the log file for port git-core for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_git-core/git-core/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port git-core failed
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that `port` has renamed the `git-core` package to just `git`. So changing the command to

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 sudo port install gmake libsdl git gnupg
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you update macports (`sudo port selfupdate`) you'll find that repo now depends on git instead of git-core.

Before:  (/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/repo/Portfile) contains:

depends_run         port:git-core

After:

port info repo

repo @1.19_1 (python)

Description:          Repo is a tool that we built on top of Git. Repo helps us
                      manage the many Git repositories, does the uploads to our
                      revision control system , and automates parts of the
                      Android development workflow. Repo is not meant to replace
                      Git, only to make it easier to work with Git in the
                      context of Android.
Homepage:             http://source.android.com/source/git-repo.html

Runtime Dependencies: git
Platforms:            darwin
License:              Apache-2
Maintainers:          nomaintainer@macports.org

or

/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/python/repo/Portfile:

depends_run         port:git

So simply use macports to install repo.